# Is possible to define same-named operator for different argument count?

Tags: syntax, f#, operators

Is possible to define same-named operator for different argument count?

And if it is possible then how?

for example I want:

```
let (-) x y = x - y
let (-) x  = -x
```

*Sadly I can't call just -x, I need (-)x to use it but it's yet another sub-question which have no relation with primary question.*

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'overload', as in, you'd like to know if you can overload operators in F#.  (I don't know F#, so I can't answer that part, sorry - but maybe a google search on 'overload F#' will work?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with let bindings

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx)

> You can redefine the regular arithmetic operators in this manner
>   because the scoping rules for F# dictate that newly defined operators
>   take precedence over the built-in operators.

However, you can use the  `static member (+)` versions with overloading ([Same MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233204.aspx))

In particular, this works:

```
> type t() =                   
-  static member (+) (a, b) = 1
-  static member (+) a = 5;;
```

Comment: Sadly that's not what I really need. I need to overload own (custom) operator in module level.

Comment: Opened the new question based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930385/how-to-declare-global-level-overload-able-operators

Comment: It is possible for _some_ operators. See my answer to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930385/how-to-declare-global-level-overload-able-operators#14931062